# Backbone routes with slash before hash redirect

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I was wondering what would be the easiest and cleanest way to add slash before hash when page is loaded without one.

Suppose I have a url **www.example.com** and I have a link which points to **www.example.com/#/test** If I click that link page will reload because browser treats www.example.com and www.example.com/ as different documents I suppose. What I want to do is silently add that slash without reloading page if it doesn't exist yet.

One thing that comes to my mind is on initialization check if trailing slash exists if not add it with push state. But maybe there is a better way to do it that I don't know yet?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put the full url in the href of your link. For example, if your site is `www.example.com`, clicking on `<a href="#hello>Click me</a>"` will change the url to `www.example.com#hello`.

Backbone treats routes the same whether or not there's a slash before the `#`.

Comment: Yes, I know that BUT it looks really ugly to me without slashes. example.com/#/test vs example.com#test... Yuck..